# How to fix this Exception Input Mismatch for this project

Tags: java

I am getting this exception and I am stumped on how to fix it.
Not sure what to do with that. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code snippet that I think is the issue, posted after the exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2387)
    at SalesRecord.main(SalesRecord.java:22)

Scanner readFile = new Scanner(productData);
    while (readFile.hasNext()) {
        String modelName = readFile.nextLine();
        int id = readFile.nextInt();
        double price = readFile.nextDouble();
        double commissionRate = readFile.nextDouble();
        productList.add(new Product(id, modelName, price, commissionRate));
    }
    readFile.close();
```

Comment: What is the type of productData in `Scanner readFile = new Scanner(productData)` ?

Comment: This is the data in the file. int followed by String, then an int i want to read as a double, then a double:
0 DX1000 700 .02
1 DX5000 1300 .03
2 SX1000 1100 .02
3 SX5000 1500 .04

Comment: Or maybe you were asking about this?
java.io.File productData = new File("/Users/User/Desktop/MidtermProject/ProductData.txt");